# automatically start node server on instance start in aws autoscaling by providing user data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a demo project in AWS and then I created an AMI for it so that I can use it for auto-scaling. now I am looking for something that I can put in user text in my launch configuration which will let me start the server without going to ssh.  I am trying out below, let me know where is my mistake.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd demo
node server.js
```

when I launch a new instance with my AMI and just do cd through SSH it works absolutely fine, however, I want to start the server with going to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

These are common one can face when running node application without [process manager](https://www.tecmint.com/process-managers-for-node-js-applications-in-linux/) on a remote server.

Let suppose the above script but what if a node application encounter error? so the application will be stopped, so better to use process manager which will take care of such thing and you will not need to do ssh.

You can use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/). Which also have slack integration another [interesting feature](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) that will help to monitor the process.

You can also set [Setup startup script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#setup-startup-script).

> Restarting PM2 with the processes you manage on server boot/reboot is
> critical. To solve this, just run this command to generate an active
> startup script:

run these command in the AMI, and pm2 will take care of the process on all instances.

```
pm2 startup
#And to freeze a process list for automatic respawn:
pm2 save
```